# Reduce time to launch Play mode and scripts update

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, ramdisk, unity3d-editor

Every working day, all unity developers have to launch the play mode in a Unity more than once. And if you think about it, it may take you a long time to wait for the launch of this mode.

My question is advise how I can speed up the launch mode and scripts update?

I have already taken the following actions:

- Created a RAM disk and installed Unity on it.
- Transferred all project-related files to the SSD (I am afraid to transfer the disc to RAM because of the possibility of losing everything in case of failure)

**EDIT:**

it running on:
i7 3770, ram ddr3 16gb(12 ram + 4 ram disk),Slim S55 240GB,gtx670

[image: launch play mode]
[image: launch update scripts]

Comment: Could you tell us something about what your current update time is and the time it takes to launch playmode. Also, what are your system specs?

Comment: During this time all `Awake`, `OnEnabled`, `Start` and other initializing methods are executed ... so if you want it to be faster, make sure you optimize your code.

Comment: There is no execution of the methods of `Awake`, `OnEnabled`, `Start` during the update of scripts. Tell me what are your indicators, but not on an empty project? Wouldn't you like to reduce them?

Comment: what do you mean by `scripts update`? You mean that you changed scripts and they are re-compiled? You can't speed this up .. only by using a better CPU etc. Also it probably better to have a lot of small classes that have a single purpose instead of huge master classes which affact a lot of dependencies once they are changed.